# how to backcheck aganist cells and data validation list?

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets, cell, spreadsheet

I've set cell A1 with data validation with list of possibilities: a,b,c,d
next I would need formula which will do this:

> - if **a** is chosen in A1 cell, set cell C1=b, C2=c, C3=d
> - if **b** is chosen in A1 cell, set cell C1=a, C2=c, C3=d
> - if **c** is chosen in A1 cell, set cell C1=a, C2=b, C3=d
> - if **d** is chosen in A1 cell, set cell C1=a, C2=b, C3=c

is there some handy formula for this purpose which I will place in cells C1, C2 and C3 which will backcheck with A1 and also between themselfs to avoid duplications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

C1:

```
=FILTER({"a";"b";"c";"d"},{"a";"b";"c";"d"}<>A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following array formula will do the job in Excel (select the range C1:C3 and use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to enter the formula):

```
=MID(REPLACE("abcd",MATCH(A1,{"a","b","c","d"},0),1,""),ROW(),1)
```

You haven't specified what you want the result to be if A1 contains neither of those values, but you may wish to wrap it in `IFERROR()`.